# Can I get a list of supported languages in my Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

I'd like to get a list of the localized cultures in my app but haven't found a way to do this. Must I hard code it in the app or is there another way?

Comment: you mean list of localized cultures which your app is translated?

Comment: Yes, how can I get a list of the translated languages at runtime without having to hard coding it?

Comment: see my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read WMAppManifest.xml file for list of translated languages. Below snippet gives required details (might need to tinker little for your final outputs)

```
XDocument.Load("WMAppManifest.xml").Root.Element("Languages").Elements("Language").Attributes();
```

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too fast to accept this answer. There's no list of translated languages in the manifest file.

Comment: I can able to see in my WP8 app manifest.xml file...
http://i.stack.imgur.com/B3EN7.png

Comment: I see, in the manifest file on Windows Phone 7 the Language element is not present but on Windows Phone 8 it is. I'll add Windows Phone 8 as tag and accept your answer.